# How to use a setter?

Tags: windev

I'm trying to change a property of a class with a setter method. But when I want to use the setter, I'm getting an error.

I generated the setter method automatically by using Windev;

`PROCÉDURE PUBLIQUE p_NuméroBDD(nValeur est un entier)`

`:m_NuméroBDD=nValeur`

When I want to use the setter:
 `:m_pclHoraires.p_NuméroBDD(:m_nNuméroBDD)`

It says, `unknown procedure`

Comment: Please share the error message you got.

Comment: It's just written "unknown procedure"

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this ?

```
:m_pclHoraires.p_NuméroBDD = nNuméroBDD
```

Comment: Does this answered your question ? You can flag it as correct answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Properties in Windev are quite similar to C# properties :
When you create getters and setters, you are able to use them as members, not as methods.

So as said previously, the correct way to call your setter is to set object.p_NuméroBDD with your value.